# Converting an Overleaf document to a Wordpress post

Tags: conversion, html, mathjax

Good morning! I have a document (math operations) made in Overleaf and I need it as a Wordpress post. Does anyone know if it is possible to perform some sort of conversion with a minimum number of errors? Some tools, anything...

<sub>**Edited by Paulo:** I took the liberty of rewording the question a bit in order to make it clearer, and translated the title as well. The original question was written in Portuguese and can be seen by browsing the edit history.</sub>

Comment: Oi Maina, seja bem-vinda! A comunidade TeX do StackExchange trata apenas de questões em inglês. Será que você poderia traduzir sua questão para o inglês? `:)`

Comment: Obrigada! desculpe a falha anterior, espero que seja possível entender.

Comment: Sobre sua questão, a resposta mais provável é que não dá para converter facilmente. Você pode tentar ferramentas de conversão de formatos como `pandoc`, mas certamente terá problemas. E é preciso lembrar que o Wordpress tem uma série de restrições quanto à sintaxe utilizada para escrita dos posts...

Comment: @Maina não se preocupe! Dê uma olhadinha no link que o Alan postou, talvez possa ajudá-la! `:)`

Comment: _A note for English-speaking users: please be gentle with the OP and let us not close this question too quickly._

Comment: Thank you, I will do it now. Hugs!

Comment: @Maina: caso a questão apontada pelo link do Alan seja diferente do que você gostaria de fazer, avise e votamos para que esta questão seja reaberta. Abraços!

Comment: @PauloCereda agradeço, mas é realmente o que preciso.

Comment: @Maina: entendi. `:)` Novamente, seja bem-vinda à comunidade!

Comment: @PauloCereda Obrigada! só mais uma duvida, devo usar o português ou o inglês? não falo inglês, então estou usando um tradutor...

Comment: @Maina Via de regra, a comunidade só aceita posts em inglês. Temos alguns usuários que falam português que podem ajudar, mas não dá pra recorrer sempre. `:)` Me avisaram no chat que havia uma questão em português, por isso vim te socorrer. `:)` Sempre que possível, use inglês. Se apertar, pode tentar recorrer ao chat da comunidade. Sigur, Phelype e eu (todos brasileiros) sempre estamos por lá: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends Boa sorte! `:)`